# Utilizar php para passar um texto multilinhas para o javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Gostaria de passar um texto com múltiplas em uma função Javascript que é montada no PHP.

```
public function change_meta_info_icon($property)
    {
        if($property['metas'] && $property['metas']['socialdb_property_help'] && !empty(trim($property['metas']['socialdb_property_help']))){
            ?>
                <button onclick="showHelpText('<?php  echo ($property['metas']['socialdb_property_help']) ?>');" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Ajuda</button>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php

    }
```

A função showHelpText deve receber o texto e passa-lo para uma janela modal mas como o texto tem '\n', parenteses, aspas e tudo mais esta gerando problemas.[image: Resultado após a execução do código]

Comment: Você quer retornar algo em php para o js é isso? Porque você não tentar passar por json?

Comment: Tem várias formas de resolver uma delas é escapar suas aspas do showhelptext(\"......, A outra é colocar todo conteúdo em uma div oculta por exemplo é passar o id da div como parâmetro do sua função ...

Comment: Valeu, acabei usando a div oculta com o texto.

Comment: @AndreAlvim Se resolveu seu problema. Marca como resolvido.